# Where'd labs.appcelerator go? (Specificly ti.Healthkit)

Tags: module, titanium, appcelerator

Now when we are required to update some modules for 64 bit support, I just found that one of our most important modules are nowhere to be found anymore.

Ti.healthkit was found previously on: https://labs.appcelerator.com/project/55c3c788e014044625e9b2a1/HealthKit-Module

Does anyone know where to find it now? Really need to somehow make sure it's upgradeable to support the latest titanium version.

Thanks

Comment: it was removed. There should be some community versions on github

Comment: Wth? No not any equivalent as the original, ive googled my ass off :-/

Comment: Use Hyperloop (https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Hyperloop) to wrap it yourself